# How to make the scrollBar Slider of a div at the bottom by default

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

First of all, Look at this picture to understand what I mean by a slider:
[image]

**Problem :**

Let's say I have a scrollable div with `height:50%` and the content is some lines so when the window is full screen I will not see a scroller like this:
[image]

But if I will resize the browser window the scroller will be like that:
[image]

So as you saw the scroller will automatically stay at the top, and here is my problem I want it to stay at the bottom (without JavaScript)?

I don't want to make it with JavaScript because I'm already using it
in some other things on the same div like (the user have the ability
to scroll app without forcing him to go down when there is an update
....), My project is a chatroom

Comment: There is now way of doing that without the use of JS/jQuery..

Comment: JavaScript can handle multiple functions/events for the same element, that shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Open Slack.com and resize the browser window and you will find exactly what I want to do ^_^

Comment: @Aziz That's tru but it's very hard to make a javascript code that will wait for the moment when the scrollbar will be visible and at that moment it will make it go down

Comment: @Aziz is there a way to put an event on the scroll bar show, this will be very helpful if it exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what I've read above, this can easily be achieved without JS/JQ.

Create an anchor at the bottom of the DIV

```
<div id='thediv'>
Your content here
<a id='bottom'>here at the bottom</a>
</div>
```

Then link to it/call it/add it to your refresh, body onload etc...

```
<a href='#bottom'>Clicky</a>
```

Or on the previous page

```
<a href='chatroom.html#bottom'>Clicky</a>
```

..and so on. Basic example:

https://jsfiddle.net/gguajng6/